# three tables side by side on one page

Tags: tables

Hi does anyone know the easiest way to put 3 table side by side like in the figure below, but with only one caption at the bottom of these tables.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is an awful and unpractical way to achieve what you want but here you go

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
|c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm} 
|c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm} 
|c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm}
}
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
Cell 1 & Cell 2 && Cell 3 & Cell 4 && Cell 5 & Cell 6 \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
Cell 1 & Cell 2 && Cell 3 & Cell 4 && Cell 5 & Cell 6 \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
Cell 1 & Cell 2 && Cell 3 & Cell 4 && Cell 5 & Cell 6 \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
Cell 1 & Cell 2 && Cell 3 & Cell 4 && Cell 5 & Cell 6 \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
Cell 1 & Cell 2 && Cell 3 & Cell 4 && Cell 5 & Cell 6 \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption here}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well it works like a magic.. exactly what i need.. thank you so much.. :)

Comment: @Sharina - Site guidelines generally suggest waiting a few hours, or even a whole day, before "accepting" an answer. That way, you don't discourage others who might be thinking about providing an alternative, and possibly better, answer. You should, of course, feel free to immediately upvote any and all answers you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add only one `caption` command in the `table` float environment. As for three tables one by one, you can directly use the `tabular` environment.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \hfill
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \hfill
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
          \hspace{4em}  &  \hspace{4em}   \\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
      \caption{Three table}\label{tab}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

gives
[image]

Comment: great this works too... @iceocean

Comment: Since the intent appears to be to spread the three `tabular` environments out as much as possible, the `\centering` instruction isn't needed.